# Spark is running queries into database multiple times

Tags: java, apache-spark, batch-processing

I'am trying to load a dataset to spark using the following code:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia3, rppDBProperties));
dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia2, rppDBProperties)));
dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia, rppDBProperties)));
dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia3, rppDBProperties)));
dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia2, rppDBProperties)));
dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia,rppDBProperties)));
dataset = dataset.cache();
Long numberOfRowsProcessed = dataset.count();
```

So after this 6 sessions hitting my database and extracting the dataset and counting the number of rows, I wouldn't need to go to the database anymore. But after running the following code:

```
dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("temp");
Dataset<Row> base =  spark.sql(new StringBuilder()
.append("select ")
.append("TRANSACTION ")
.append("from temp ")
.append("where PAYMENT_METHOD in (1,2,3,4) ")
.append("and   TRANSACTION_STATUS in ('A','B') ")
.toString()
);
base.createOrReplaceTempView("base");
```

But, what I am actually seeing is spark running again the query, but this time, appending the filters I passed when defining `Dataset<Row> base`. And as you can see, I already cached the data, but it had no effect.

**Question**: Is that possible to load everything in memory in spark and use the cached data, querying spark and not anymore the database?

To fetch the data from my relational database is expensive and taking a while to do so.

**UPDATE**

I could notice that spark is sending new queries to the database when it tries to execute

```
from base a 
left join base b on on a.IDT_TRANSACTION = b.IDT_TRANSACTION and a.DATE = b.DATE
```

This is the string spark is appending to the query (captured from the database):

```
WHERE ("IDT_TRANSACTION_STATUS" IS NOT NULL) AND ("NUM_BIN_CARD" IS NOT NULL)
```

In the log appears:

> 18/01/16 14:22:20 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 12 (show at
>   RelatorioBinTransacao.java:496) finished in 13,046 s 18/01/16 14:22:20
>   INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages 18/01/16 14:22:20
>   INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set(ShuffleMapStage 9) 18/01/16 14:22:20
>   INFO DAGScheduler: waiting: Set(ShuffleMapStage 13, ShuffleMapStage
>   10, ResultStage 14, ShuffleMapStage 11) 18/01/16 14:22:20 INFO
>   DAGScheduler: failed: Set()

I'm not sure if I get what is trying to say, but I think something is missing in memory.

If I just add comments on the left join like this:

```
from base a 
//left join base b on on a.IDT_TRANSACTION = b.IDT_TRANSACTION and a.DATE = b.DATE
```

it works just fine and it doesn't go to the database anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way to workaround the problem. I had to add a `cache()` instruction to every line I sent queries to the database. So it looks like this:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, fake, rppDBProperties);
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia3, rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia2, rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, creditoDia, rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia3, rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia2, rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.union(spark.read().jdbc(RPP_CONNECTION_URL, debitoDia,rppDBProperties).cache());
        dataset = dataset.cache();
```

I had to add the first line of `fake` sql, because no matter what I did, spark seems not to consider caching the first query, so I kept seeing the first query being sent to the database.

Bottom line, I don't understand why I have to add a `cache()` instruction to every line if I already did it at the end. But, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may not have enough memory to store the unioned results on your cluster. After `Long numberOfRowsProcessed = dataset.count();` please look at the Storage tab of your Spark UI to see if the whole dataset is fully cached or not. If it is NOT then you need more memory (and/or disk space).

If you've confirmed the dataset is indeed cached then please post the query plan (e.g. `base.explain()`).

Comment: I tried to add `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2()` on each line of my spark.read().jdbc, but still executing the queries appending the filters on the database. I will try to see the Storage tab and get back to you soon.

Comment: I'm running using `.setMaster('local[*]')`

Comment: So you're running in local mode? What have you set as driver/executor memory?

Comment: I build a java application with spark libs inside and run `java -Xmx25g -cp myjar.jar org.pack.MyClass`

Comment: Just found out which spark sql is sending queries to the database
`.append("from base a ")
.append("left join (select distinct date, idt_transaction from base where idt_transaction_status = 9 and num_bin_card is not null) b ")
.append("on a.IDT_TRANSACTION = b.IDT_TRANSACTION and a.DATE = b.DATE ")`

when I left join base, which is the TempView I already created, It send again queries to the database. If I take it the left join, it just doesn't send anymore queries and works OK.

The question is: why if I already cached base table and already accessed it?

Comment: That still shouldn't be happening. Also, I noticed your storage tab says 200% cached which I've seen sometimes when it re-caches the original data. What are you setting your SparkConfig values to besides `master` (e.g. driver memory, executor memory).